# How can I manipulate an advanced search url to work with a form?

Tags: magento-1.9, url

I use search boxes throughout my site with this code-

```
<form action="/catalogsearch/result/" method="get">
```

And everything works great. I am now trying to use this same method with advanced search. The purpose is to only search within a single attribute. In my case this url works great-
/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?manufacturer=26&name=single+phase

The problem I am running into is if I try to use this code-

```
<form action="/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?manufacturer=26"  method="get">
```

It doesn't work. It seems like it strips ?manufacturer=26, but even if it didn't strip off the ? I don't think a url would work with two separate ? anyway. Anyone have any idea to fix this? Or a different idea to create a search by an attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `manufacturer` as a product attribute, you can put a hidden field with name `manufacturer` in your advanced search form like below.

```
<input type="hidden" name="manufacturer" id="manufacturer" value="26" />
```

When you submit your form, the parameter will pass automatically to your url.

Comment: I thought it worked but it didn't. It just returns all things under the manufacturer. It doesn't include the search term.

Comment: Can you please add your form code to your question ?

Comment: I got it. I needed to change name="q" to name="name"